# Sencha Touch - App watch sass

Tags: extjs, ant, sass, sencha-touch, compass

Since compass no longer works with the latest version of Sencha Touch, I looked for a way to compile my sass and I found `sencha ant sass` does the trick. But I found that executing the command each time I changed my sass was a bit annoying so I found `sencha app watch` that watches for **ANY** changes inside the application, whether it is sass or source code, and build the whole thing.

Is there a way to `sencha app watch` only sass code ?

EDIT:
Using `Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)` `Sencha Cmd v5.0.3.324` `SenchaTouch 2.4.0`

Comment: Wow, which version of Sencha are you using? compass watch works perfectly for me. (version 2.4.0)

Comment: "Since compass no longer works..." How isn't it working?

Comment: @sherb I read in a blog post by the Ext team that compass no longer understands the new file structure of SenchaTouch apps. It gives me errors about undefined mixins and stuff inside the `touch` folder that I haven't modified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Run your command with:

```
sencha ant sass -watch
```

It will monitor the sass files for changes and compile them on the fly just same as compass native command.